# Regex PCRE field extraction

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to extract a user field from the following events using regex.

Mon Aug 06 2018 19:35:34 whostname sshd[4191]: Failed password for backup from 27.96.191.11 port 3558 ssh2

Mon Aug 06 2018 19:35:59 whostname sshd[5625]: Failed password for nobody from 27.96.191.11 port 1574 ssh2

Mon Aug 06 2018 19:36:07 whostname sshd[3840]: Failed password for invalid user uni from 27.96.191.11 port 4916 ssh2

Mon Aug 06 2018 19:36:26 whostname sshd[66863]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user michael by (uid=0)

Mon Aug 06 2018 19:36:26 whostname sshd[1573]: Failed password for invalid user harry from 27.96.191.11 port 1025 ssh2

For the first event user field is "backup" and for second event it is "nobody" and for 3rd its "uni" and 4th its "michael"and for 5th its "harry"

I have tried different regex with no sucess

Eg: https://regex101.com/r/52GMc4/1

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: If these cases describe all possible contexts, try [`for(?:\s+invalid)?(?:\s+user)?\s+(?<User>\w+)\s+(?:by|from)`](https://regex101.com/r/52GMc4/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also test for the possibility of the words `user`and `invalid user` appear before your user name. The following matches all your test strings

```
/for(?:\s(?:invalid\s)?user)?\s+(?<User>\w+)/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response. Other 2 answers also worked but yours has taken less steps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not as elegant but you'll find the user name captured in the second group:

```
/(password for|invalid user|opened for user) (\w+)/gi
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/52GMc4/3)